# How to have plots generated via TensorBoard captured by Jupyter notebook downloaded as PDF?

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, tensorboard

I'm using TensorBoard as part of the Jupyter notebook. In the end, I need to download the notebook as PDF. The issue that I have is that none of the plots generated via TensorBoard is captured in the PDF document.
The only way to include the plots(that I know of) would be to check the box “Show data download links” and download the plots as SVG and eventually massage the PDF document. While the job can be done this way, still is not the most elegant/productive approach.
Wondering if anyone faced the same issue and came up with a programmatic solution.